# IP_TRANSPARENT missing from glibc headers

Tags: linux, compiling, c

I'm trying to use the `IP_TRANSPARENT` declaration. I am using debian 6.0.5. IP_TRANSPARENT is only defined in `linux/in.h` however it conflicts with `netinet/in.h`.
In centos for example, `IP_TRANSPARENT` is defined in both `linux/in.h` and `bits/in.h`.

When I look at the top of `bits/in.h` (which I get when I include `netinet/in.h`, the centos one has

```
/* Copyright (C) ... 2008, 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Whereas one in my debian install has

```
/* Copyright (C) ... 2004, 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I've tried

```
apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686
```

But it says it is already the newest version. How do I update the debian linux headers to the latest versions?

**Edit:**

In centos, `IP_TRANSPARENT` is defined in `bits/in.h`, which I get if I include `netinet/in.h`. It compiles fine under centos.

In debian, `IP_TRANSPARENT` is not in `bits/in.h`, so when I include `netinet/in.h` I get a `‘IP_TRANSPARENT’ undeclared` error when compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you already have the right versions, but `linux/in.h` is a kernel header that you should not be trying to include directly in a user space program.

You also shouldn't include `bits/in.h` as that is a header fragment that will be included by other headers when necessary.

The `netinet/in.h` is what you should be including and that will, in turn, include the `bits/in.h` header. If that doesn't have a definition for `IP_TRANSPARENT` then the version of glibc on the system is too old.

If you can't update `glibc` because you are already on the latest version offered by your distribution then the pragmatic solution, and the one which will make your program portable, is to add the following to your code:

```
#ifndef IP_TRANSPARENT
#define IP_TRANSPARENT  19
#endif
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean forget about the other declarations, do you mean I should #define IP_TRANSPARENT in my own program instead?

In centos, IP_TRANSPARENT is defined in bits/in.h, which I get if I include netinet/in.h.

In debian, IP_TRANSPARENT is not in bits/in.h, so when I include netinet/in.h I get a ‘IP_TRANSPARENT’ undeclared error when compiling.

Comment: Well `netinet/in.h` should be including `bits/in.h` I think - it does on my Fedora systems.

Comment: Hi, yes I meant while I should only include netinet/in.h, on my debian install, bits/in.h doesn't define IP_TRANSPARENT. which is causing my compile errors.
It compiles fine on centos as bits/in.h defines IP_TRANSPARENT because it is newer (dated 2010) than the debian one (dated 2008). I've updated the original question to clarify this.

Comment: It sounds like the version of `glibc` that your distribution has too old then - if there is no newer version (which it sounds like there isn't) then you need a newer distribution. Pragmatically it may be easier to add a define (guarded by ifdef) to your code to make it portable to older systems.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that explains it; centos `rpm -q glibc` shows glibc-2.12 while on debian
`apt-cache show libc6` shows glibc-2.11.
I can't upvote your last comment or mark it as an answer though - assuming updating glibc will update the headers. Or do I upvote and mark your original answer (even though strictly speaking it didn't answer the question?)

Comment: @AG Just wait for TomH to hopefully post a new answer or edit his existing one to include the correct answer, and then you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've updated my answer - you should probably also change the question title to something more useful like "IP_TRANSPARENT missing from glibc headers?"